# English names for vector beginning and end

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, terminology

I've done some research, but since English is not my native language, I'm struggling to find an answer to this:

Given a vector, what do you call its beginning and end points?

The best I've found so far is the word "base" for the beginning point of a vector, but I have no clue if that's correct. The best I've got for the end point is the "tip" of the vector, although the same applies as before.

Comment: Could also call them head and tail

Comment: Note that this is one of those situations where physicists and mathematicians disagree.  To a physicist, it makes perfect sense for a vector to have a head and a tail, but a mathematician would insist that vectors are rooted at 0.

Comment: @JacobManaker At least in _Elementary Topics in Differential Geometry_, Thorpe talks about $\mathbb R^n_p = \{p\} \times \mathbb R^n$ as the vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ "in the point $p$". So such a thing does seem to exist in mathematics as well. :)

Comment: Completely different domain, but I immediately thought of C++'s `std::vector::begin()` and `std::vector::end()` member functions

Comment: @tomsmeding: Only if we're talking about vector *bundles*, not plain old vectors as elements of a vector space, surely?

Comment: @Rahul Vector bundles, elements of tangent spaces, etc. Indeed, elements of vector spaces are still "normal" vectors, $\mathbb R^n$ is still the usual vector space.

Comment: @JacobManaker My perspective (being a former physicist, and representative of some portion of the field I think) would be that "position vectors" have heads and tails, but these objects are not truly vectors. I'd say an actual vector has a direction (among other properties) but not a location. Of course one might talk about a vector being associated with a particular point, as in a tangent vector, but that's something more than just a plain old vector.

Comment: @Ben, as I mentioned in another comment, this is exactly the reason why I couldn't find the answer myself. Looking for "vector begin end" yields that kind of result :)

Comment: @Ben: Same here!

Comment: @tomsmeding As a mathematician, I disagree: A vector is just an element of a vector space. If the vector space happens to be $\mathbb{R}^n$, a vector is also an equivalence class of arrows (i.e., what physicists might call a vector with head and tail) under translation. The arrows rooted at 0 would be one example of representatives of these equivalence classes, but addition of such vectors would probably use a different one for the graphical explanation. (Something like what David Z said, just using words I think have an unambiguous definition.)

Comment: The tag "linear algebra" suggests the interpretation of "vector" as element of some \mathbb{R}^n , but nothing in the axiomatic definition of a vector implies that vector may have anything remotely resembling a start and an end. For example, the elements of the vector space ${C}_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$ of continuous functions in \mathbb{R}^2 that vanish at infinity do not have any feature that can be naturally called "base", or "head", or "start", etc.

Comment: @NebojsaMrmak what do you mean by "vector"?

Comment: @VictorZurkowski, it is now becoming obvious that a vector in mathematics has a different connotation than in physics. What I was referring to can be illustrated by this (taken from wikipedia article on shear force:  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e2/Shear_crack.svg/70px-Shear_crack.svg.png
I'm struggling to embed a picture here, but the link will do. These two vectors don't start at (0,0,0), but have a starting point and an ending point, otherwise they would not make sense in engineering terms.

Comment: I don't think there are special technical names for the "tip" or the "tail" of vectors in applications. Forces and velocities are drawn with arrows, but stress tensors (in the context of elastic bodies), which are vectors, do not have a meaningful "tip" or "tail" to speak of; stress tensors are applied at a point. If in your situation you can draw an arrow to describe the vector, the words to describe the features of the arrow will work: tip, tail or starting point, ending point, or beginning, end, etc would be understood. Do you have an answer in another language?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A good question. Since an important property of a vector is its direction it is hard to talk about vectors without having words for where they start and end.

In my experience we have generally called the source or beginning of a vector its "tail" and the destination or end of the vector its "head".

[image: Picture]

Comment: I have more often heard "tip" instead of "head", but I'm sure that both would be understood.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll give some more time for people to chime in, but this most likely answers my question.

Comment: I prefer "tip" because then the graphical method of vector addition is the "tip to tail" method, which is nicely alliterative.  However, a quick Google reveals that it is also known (less commonly) as the "head to tail" method as well.

Answer (score 9):

They are sometimes called the initial and terminal points. The initial point is the point at which starts and the terminal point is the point at which it ends.

Answer (score 5):

The [Wikipedia article *Euclidean vector*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) says that when you construct a vector, called $\overrightarrow{AB}$, from two points $A$ and $B$ in Euclidean space, then $A$ is called ***initial point***, and $B$ is called ***terminal point***.

It all depends on what your definition of a vector is, of course. For example, it is common to consider a vector as an equivalence class of all those oriented line segments of this kind that have the same length (magnitude) and the same direction. With such a definition, a "vector" has no initial point and no terminal point, although you can pick any initial point you like and consider the *representative* oriented line segment originating from that point.

In the more general setting of a smooth manifold, you often have a tangent vector in the particular [tangent space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) (or fiber) $T_pM$ that corresponds to a point $p$ in the manifold. In such a case, you need both this *foot point* (is this the common name?) $p$ and a representation of the vector in the tangent space "sitting" at that point. In this general setting, there is no canonical equivalence between a vector in $T_pM$ and a vector in another fiber $T_qM$ (here $q\ne p$ is another point in the manifold $M$).

Usually, when $v\in T_pM$, we just say that $v$ is a tangent vector ***"at"*** $p$. As I said, I think I heard $p$ being called the *foot point* of $v$.

Answer (score -3):

Uh, you aren't actually talking about a vector here.  A vector is not defined by a beginning and end point.  It has a direction and magnitude (and equivalents in other coordinate systems) but no fixed origin.

The vector might have a *location* where the coordinates are taken.  This is particularly relevant in curvilinear coordinate systems.  If you draw a vector there, you typically draw the respective arrow with its base on the location of the vector, its shaft being straight and tangential to the coordinate directions at the origin of the vector, and the component sizes being in proportion.

Sometimes arrows are drawn for directed line segments.  Those do have a starting and an ending point.  In that case, the shafts of those arrows will *follow* any curvilinear coordinate system.  Visualizing a directed line segment specified by starting point and displacement vector is rarely done when more than one coordinate is actually changing since then the *path* along which the displacement is achieved has no obvious candidate: there is no obviously preferred route between starting and ending point any more.

Comment: The tone of the question suggests that the OP is specifically talking about _localised vectors_ and not _free vectors_, so it's implicit to answer about the former.